Unable to publish dependencies to my private repository
I am unfamliar with npm packages and node. I have a package.json file with a package with many dependencies. A node_modules dir in the same dir contains all the modules. When attempting to publish to our AWS codeartifact repo with 'npm publish --registry="https://example-repo.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/npm/registry-name/", only the package gets uploaded, not the dependencies. Is there a reason for this?
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "registry": "https://example-repo.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/npm/registry-name/",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:ui": "vitest --ui --coverage.enabled=true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@axa-fr/react-oidc": "^7.22.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.29.2",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.29.2",
    "amazon-connect-streams": "^2.14.1",
    "amazon-connect-taskjs": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "babel-plugin-add-react-displayname": "^0.0.5",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "logrocket": "^8.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "pino": "^8.20.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primereact": "10.5.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.7.2",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^6.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.15.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.11.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yup": "^1.4.0",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.6.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^1.5.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.75.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.9",
    "vitest": "^1.5.0"
  }
}


This is how the npm publish command works. It does not upload the package's dependencies. If you think about publishing to npmjs.com (what npm publish was originally intended to do), all the dependencies are already present in the remote registry.
If you want all the dependencies from npmjs.com to be present in your CodeArtifact repository, create an external connection to npmjs.com, clear your npm cache and then build the module. All the dependencies will be downloaded from CodeArtifact and persisted in your CodeArtifact repository. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/external-connection.html for how to set this up.
